# How to list objects in an object in html?

Tags: html, node.js, angular, ngfor

I'm writing app in Angular and Node.js. I have an object (order) that has a list of objects (items) that also contain objects (list of product id). I want to display them all in an html file. Please help me.

html file:[image]

```
<div *ngIf="order">
    <div *ngFor="let item of order.items"> // <- it does not work
        <a>{{order.items}}</a> // <--
    </div>
</div>
```

ts file:

```
export class AdminOrderItemComponent implements OnInit {
  order: Order;
  orderId;
  constructor(private orderService: OrderService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap
      .subscribe(params => {
        this.orderId = [params.get('id')];
        this.getOrderById();
      });
  }
  getOrderById() {
    this.orderService.getOrderById(this.orderId).subscribe(
      res => {
        this.order = res;
      },
      err => console.log(err)
    );
  }
}
```

order interface:

```
export interface Order  {
  _id: any;
  shipping: string;
  userData: {};
  sum: number;
  items: {};
}
```

Comment: try <div *ngFor="let item of order.items | keyvalue">
    Key: <b>{{item.key}}</b> and Value: <b>{{item.value}}</b>
</div>. Have a look at https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe

Comment: After this solution, it shows list "Key: 5f96e3ea56ad9f13901bd8d1 and Value: [object Object]".  It's almost what I wanted, but how to show this "[object Object]" ?

Comment: You can access the object's properties.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works. <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from @kg99:

Key: **{{item.key}}** and Value: **{{item.value}}**

Answer (score 0):

The [ngFor](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) iterates over the items of a collection. If you take a look at your model, you will realize that items is an object (`{}`), not an array (`[]`).

Your best bet is transforming the object received from your node.js backend to match your  needs or (preferably I think) make your node.js model treat items as a collection as well which seems more appropriate.